# Remove pipe characters from tracking code?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have an old project was written way back in the days and uses the pipe character ( **|** ) as separator between some data.

Google analytics tracking code includes a pipe character:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', '', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

When i give the tracking code to the project it gives an error because of the pipe character used.

Is it possible to remove / replace the 2 pipe character from the tracking code but keep the tracking code functional?

That would save me a lot of hacking in old code ;-)

Comment: the double pipe characters you are referring to is an OR check.  i suppose u can rewrite the code to remove it.

Comment: @BennyLin yes, that's right, but this doesn't seem an OR the way i know and use OR's like: if(x || y){} . But I'm not really a javascript expert, that is actually why I'm asking the question, i didn't think that messing with obfuscated code is a good idea.

Comment: The Google Analytics tracking code should not be altered in *any* way. Doing so could affect the way it behaves and collects data. As mentioned, the double pipes is an OR operator. In this case it just says "i[r] is equal to i[r] (if it exists) OR it is equal to a function defined as such (if i[r] doesn't exist)...". In summary, you would need to rewrite your own code to work around the GA code.

Comment: @nyuen that's just to scare people off, you can change anything as long as you know what you change. But indeed it of course is better not to do it, why take the chance, unless you need to change because of external factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be *much, much* better to fix the code that is tripping over `|` characters.

A bad, but effective alternative would be to put the code in a string, but replace each `|` with the equivalent unicode escape sequence, which is `\u007C`.

```
// EXPLANATORY COMMENT GOES HERE
var scriptEncoded =
"(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]\u007C\u007Cfunction(){ \
(i[r].q=i[r].q\u007C\u007C[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), \
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) \
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');";

eval(scriptEncoded);

ga('create', '', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

In case it's not clear, this works because in JavaScript, as in many languages, [you can use a Unicode escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Unicode_escape_sequences) as a substitute for any character. For example, `console.log("\u0066\u006F\u006F")` will print `foo` to the console, because those are the escape sequences for `f` and `o`.

Note that:

1. Each line in the string ends with `\`, which is necessary with line breaks in a string. (You could also just take out the line breaks, but I think that's less readable.)
2. You *really* need a comment at the top of the script explaining why this is happening because it's a kludge and the next person looking at your code is going to see that `eval` and rightly wonder WTF is going on.

Comment: This looks like a really nice solution, going to try it tomorrow, but I'm sure it is going to work. Thanks for the great workaround! Changing an entire project (with all related risks) or simply changing the counter code, you made the choice easy ;-)